# Pthread Xlib programming

Tags: c, pthreads, x11, xlib

I am very new to pthread and xlib programming. I am trying to draw and move two sets of rectangles in opposite direction but my problem when I run my code only one of the threads is executed and the other one is ignored.

I have tried several options but to no avail. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I have included my source code.

Thanks.

Compile: gcc -o Demofinal Demofinal.c -lpthread -lX11

Run: ./Demofinal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <pthread.h>
//Compile gcc -o Demofinal Demofinal.c -lpthread -lX11
//Run ./Demofinal

Display *dis;
Window win;
XEvent report;
GC green_gc;
XColor green_col;
Colormap colormap;
pthread_mutex_t mutexsum;

char green[] = "#00FF00";
void *createMoveLogs( void *ptr );
typedef struct str_thdata
{
int xval;
int yval;
int dir;
} thdata;

int main() {

pthread_t mvleft, mvright;
thdata data1, data2;        

/* initialize data to pass to thread 1 and 2*/
    data1.xval = 600;
    data1.yval = 115;
    data1.dir = 0;

    data2.xval = 5;
    data2.yval = 250;
    data2.dir = 1;



dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dis, RootWindow(dis, 0), 1, 1, 550, 550, 0, WhitePixel (dis, 0), WhitePixel(dis, 0));
XMapWindow(dis, win);
colormap = DefaultColormap(dis, 0);
green_gc = XCreateGC(dis, win, 0, 0);
XParseColor(dis, colormap, green, &green_col);
XAllocColor(dis, colormap, &green_col);
XSetForeground(dis, green_gc, green_col.pixel);

pthread_create( &mvleft, NULL, createMoveLogs, (void*) &data1);//thread 1 move right to left
pthread_create( &mvright, NULL, createMoveLogs, (void*) &data2);//thread 2 move left to right
pthread_join(mvleft, NULL);
pthread_join(mvright, NULL);    
return 0;
   }

  void *createMoveLogs( void *ptr )
  {
thdata *data;            
    data = (thdata *) ptr;

    int x= data->xval; int y = data->yval; int i;
int direction =  data->dir;
//check if the direction to move == left
if(direction == 0){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
    for(i=0; i<=600; i++){
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x+200, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x+400, y, 145, 50);
        x-=10;
        if (x==-500){x=data->xval; i=0;}

        usleep(100000);
        XFlush(dis);
        XClearWindow(dis, win);
    } 
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexsum);
}else if(direction == 1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
    for(i=0; i<=600; i++){

        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x-200, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x-400, y, 145, 50);
        x+=10;
        if (x==855){x=5; i=0;}
        usleep(100000);
        XFlush(dis);
        XClearWindow(dis, win);
    } 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
  }
   }
```

Comment: Only one thread at a time can do X11 calls

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch so you mean what I am trying to do will be impossible? or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Indeed, I suggest to have only one single thread doing Xlib calls. With toolkits like GTK or QT, only the main thread can do GUI calls. If you absolutely want to have several threads doing X11 (which is wrong to me), use a mutex for serialization and don't forget to often call Xsync.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well I have no other option its a requirement for the work I am doing and yes thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately I must X11 to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2):

## DO NOT RUN THIS IS YOU ARE SENSITIVE TO FLASHING LIGHTS.

```
XInitThreads(); 
...

if(direction == 0){
    for(i=0; i<=600; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
        printf ("Thread %d\n", direction);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x+200, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x+400, y, 145, 50);
        x-=10;
        if (x==-500){x=data->xval; i=0;}

        XFlush(dis);
        XClearWindow(dis, win);
        usleep(50000);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexsum);
        usleep(50000);
    }
}else if(direction == 1){
    for(i=0; i<=600; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
        printf ("Thread %d\n", direction);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x-200, y, 145, 50);
        XDrawRectangle(dis, win, green_gc, x-400, y, 145, 50);
        x+=10;
        if (x==855){x=5; i=0;}
        XFlush(dis);
        XClearWindow(dis, win);
        usleep(50000);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexsum);
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```

This displays both sets of moving rectangles. Of course the method is completely barbarian, as `XClearWindow()` causes constant flicker. In a real program each thread would be responsible for clearing its own part of the old frame, without touching others' parts.

Answer (score 1):

Xlib support for calls from multiple threads only works if you call [XInitThreads()](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man3/XInitThreads.3.xhtml) *before* calling any other Xlib function.   Even with that, there are some bugs still, but without it, there’s no attempt to do proper locking or synchronization between threads.

Answer (score 0):

You have the looping and `usleep()` calls *inside* of the mutex locks, meaning that the first thread to execute will lock the other one out forever.

Comment: @geekosuar That was the last one I tried doing. It stays the same even without the mutex.. Thank you.

Comment: Without the mutex you'd be lucky not to get a core dump, since I don't see an `XInitThreads()` in there anywhere.  Xlib really isn't threadsafe; you're best off not trying to use threads at all.